# No external links in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, links

I have a very weird problem using the `hyperref` package. When I try to link an external web site it doesn't work and only show me the link which it is pointing to. I've tried this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Here's a link to \href{http://twitter.com/home}{Twitter}.

\end{document}
```

but the result is always negative. I click the link and it displays the toast with the web address. The weird fact though is that when I use the `moderncv` package and link my mail address with the macro `\email` it works, so I guess the problem is with my `\hyperref` but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) From your MWE I have no problems in opening the url.

Comment: Hi Luigi, could you tell us your operating system, TeX distro and PDF viewer? `:)`

Comment: The problem might be your pdf viewer's configuration and not LaTeX. What happens when you click a URL/link in a pdf that wasn't created with LaTeX? If the problem appears there, too, we should probably migrate this question to [su].

Comment: You are right :-). I am using pdflatex to compile and this is the version pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011). I'm under Ubuntu 12.04 and use emacs23 as text editor and acroread file.pdf to see the file

Comment: I've tried to open it with Document Viewer (as an alternative to Acrobat) but the problem is the same

Comment: What does 'the result is always negative' mean?  If by 'Document Viewer', you mean `evince`, when you click on the link, do you get a warning along the lines of "Unable to open external link"?  If so, this is not a TeX problem.

Comment: Yes I mean evince and I don't get any message or warning in the terminal, I simply get a toast in the document with the link's name

Comment: I've partially solved the issue by using Okular as pdfViewer. I use the word partially because if I try to send the file to someone not using Okular they are still unable to get the links opened and that's not what I want. By the way right this is the best I can do, hope to find a better answer asap.

Comment: Which version of `hyperref` do you use? I think nobody can reproduce this problem.

Comment: Assuming it is the one given by issuing
$ latex --version

it is 6.0.1 (Tex Live 2011)

I've tried from a couple my friends' pc and the problem was the same.

I've tried the following visualizer:

evince, acroread, okular

Comment: I've tried your MWE and it works perfect for me. I'm using `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)` and `Package: hyperref 2012/05/13 v6.82q Hypertext links for LaTeX`. I viewed the pdf with the actual SumatraPDF. Seems to be a problem of your installation?

Comment: Seems like I have to install it again... Is there a ''magic command'' to do it without pain?

Comment: Does `hyperref`'s internal macro `\hyper@linkurl{<text>}{<url>}` work for you?

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install texlive-full, sudo apt-get update and then I compiled again the pdf but the problem is still there...

Comment: @cgnieder what is the usage of hyper@linkurl? ùtex says it is an unknown command

Comment: I suppose by »ùtex« you mean »LaTeX«? It's as simple as I posted it. Of course you have to enclose it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because of the `@` in its name. (If it works one could define a more user-friendly command)

Comment: Yes sorry I meant Latex. I tried your suggestion and successfully get an hyperlink in the text but when I click on it I have the same behavior I had before. Tried with acroread and evince.

Comment: With the command pdflatex --version I get pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011), was the upgrade successful? I was sure I had installed the last version...

Comment: Luigi, you wrote about “I tried sudo apt-get …” This looks to me, as that you installed the outdated (!!!) TeX Live version from the repository of your Linux distro. Perhaps it includes an old version of `hyperref` with a bug, that was fixed later. See also [How to install “ vanilla ” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).